# How can I make a dataclass hash the same as a string?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, python-dataclasses

I want to replace string keys in dictionaries in my code with a `dataclass` so that I can provide meta data to the keys for debugging. However, I still want to be able to use a string to lookup dictionaries. I tried implementing a data-class with a replaced `__hash__` function, however my code is not working as expected:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(eq=True, frozen=True)
class Key:
    name: str

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

k = "foo"
foo = Key(name=k)

d = {}
d[foo] = 1

print(d[k])  # Key Error
```

The two hash functions are the same:

```py
print(hash(k) == hash(foo))  # True
```

So I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: `Key(name="foo") != "foo"` - `foo` is equal to other `Key`s with the same name, but not to a string.

Comment: If you want to associate metadata with keys, the right way to do that is to make it part of the value. (Or maybe use a second dict for that.)

Comment: @user2457112 I want to replace all strings in my code with classes, as they have caused so many bugs previously (spelling mistakes) and dont play nicely with IDEs (when you refactor, the keys with the same values dont get changed in other sections of the code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two objects having different hashes guarantees that they're different, but two objects having the same hash doesn't in itself guarantee that they're the same (because hash collisions exist).  If you want the `Key` to be considered equal to a corresponding `str`, implement that in `__eq__`:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Key):
            return self.name == other.name
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.name == other
        return False
```

This fixes the `KeyError` you're encountering.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that this is not an alternative to setting the hash value as shown in the question, but an addition, because equal object must have the same hash?

Comment: a slightly more efficient approach (timed with `timeit`) could be `def __eq__(self, other): return self.name == getattr(other, 'name', other)`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my notes here from the comments on [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73870057/10237506), as no one looks at those in any case, so those are likely to get swept under the rug at some point.

- PyCharm also produces a helpful warning:

  > 'eq' is ignored if the class already defines '`__eq__`' method.

  I think this means to remove the `eq=True` usage as well, from the `@dataclass(...)` decorator.
- technically, you could also remove the last `if isinstance(..., str):` as well as the last `return` statement. I'm not entirely sure what would be the implications of that, however.

Here then, is a slightly more optimized approach (timings with `timeit` module below):

```py
class Key:
    name: str

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == getattr(other, 'name', other)
```

#### Timings with `timeit`

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from timeit import timeit


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Key:
    name: str

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Key):
            return self.name == other.name
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.name == other
        return False


class KeyTwo(Key):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == getattr(other, 'name', other)


k = "foo"
foo = Key(name=k)
foo_two = KeyTwo(name=k)

print('__eq__() Timings --')
print('isinstance():  ',  timeit("foo == k", globals=globals()))
print('getattr():     ', timeit("foo_two == k", globals=globals()))

assert foo == foo_two == k
```

Results on my **M1 Mac**:

```
__eq__() Timings --
isinstance():   0.10553250007797033
getattr():      0.08371329202782363
```